# Render Multiple Controls To Image

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can I render multiple controls (or the same control) to a bitmap on specified locations. For example render control1 in it's full size to the location (50;50) and control2 at location (100;100) and so forth.

I've a control that needs to be rendered 6 times side-by-side on an image with a single property changed in each rendering.

RenderTargetBitmap has the render function, but it doesn't allow me to specify where on the image I want my control rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try positioning the controls in a canvas, then render the canvas to a bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

When you have your bitmap renderings you can put them inside a [DrawingGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawinggroup.aspx) which allows you to specify exactly where in the resulting drawing they should be drawn.

To put images inside a drawinggroup, you'd have to use [ImageDrawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagedrawing.aspx). There's an example that does this on the DrawingGroup msdn page linked above.